# pass Rails conditional statement to where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a dropdown in a form and based on what the user selects I need to perform different queries.  What's the best way to accomplish this?  Could I have 2 functions where I get the privacy_level and then process what query to use in order to pass that value to the 2nd function?

```
  def get_article_restrictions(privacy_level)
     case privacy_level
     when 0
       "#{@authenticated_user.id} = articles.user_id"
     when 1
       "query 1"
     when 2
       "query 2"
     end
  end
```

in the 2nd function I would use whatever query was returned from the 1st function.

```
def display_articles
  privacy_level = get_article_restrictions(params[:privacy_level])
  @articles = Article.includes(:user).where(privacy_level)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the query you need to perform. If it's just a simple `where`, you can pass a hash with `where` params:

```
  def get_article_restrictions(privacy_level)
     case privacy_level
     when 0
       { "articles.user_id": @authenticated_user.id }
     when 1
       { param1: value1, param2: value2 }
     when 2
       { param3: value3, param4: value4 }
     end
  end

def display_articles
  privacy_level = get_article_restrictions(params[:privacy_level])
  @articles = Article.includes(:user).where(privacy_level)
end
```

I would suggest doing it the other way around: pass the scope to the method:

```
def fetch_articles(scope, privacy_level)
     case privacy_level
     when 0
       scope.where("articles.user_id": @authenticated_user.id)
     when 1
       scope.where(param1: value1, param2: value2)
     when 2
       scope.where(param3: value3, param4: value4)
     end
end

def display_articles
  @articles = fetch_articles(Article.includes(:user), params[:privacy_level])
end
```

I'd also suggest to move `fetch_articles` to the modes, as calling active record methods (like `where`) causes too much coupling and makes testing harder.

Answer (score 0):

mrzasa suggested in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53565808/3982562) to move the method to a model. Here is an example of how this could look.

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  # ...

  def self.privacy_level(level, user)
    case level
    when 0
      where(user_id: user.id)
    when 1
      where(attribute: 'value')
    when 2
      where(attribute: 'value')
    else
      # Return the current scope without adding constraints.
      where(nil)
    end
  end

  # ...
end
```

Then in the controller simply call the scope.

```
def display_articles
  @articles = Article.includes(:user)
                     .privacy_level(params[:privacy_level], @authenticated_user)
end
```

Keep in mind that most request parameters arive as strings, meaning only the *else* case is going to match. You can resolve this by changing the cases to `when 0, '0'` instead of `when 0`.

You might also want to move the default case into the else statement. This way when no level is given (`params[:privacy_level]` equals `nil`) you still constrain the fetched records.